# Where can I ask (if I can ask) about Android hardware?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a couple of questions that I'd love to have answered on SE about modifying Android hardware; however, those questions [aren't on topic at Android](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1786/65853) (which is only about "Android the platform"), [nor on SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8270/333963) (don't even *think about* picking up a soldering iron!).

**Is there a Stack Exchange site where *modifying Android hardware* is on-topic?**

Comment: What component(s) are you looking to modify?  The reason I ask is that it *may* be possible to word the questions around those specific components in a way that could be on topic on other sites.

Comment: Poke around http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android and see if those are the kinds of things you are interested in.

Comment: @SabreTooth Right now, adding a GPS transmitter/receiver to my $20 tablet, possibly also adding more memory.

Comment: @jonsca Thanks for the recommendation. Those do look like the kind of question that I'm interested in. I've never used that site, though....do they write their answers so that newbies to the field (like myself) could understand, or are they more of a professionals-only place?

Comment: I agree with @jonsca, EE.SE maybe the way to go - now you got me intrigued, as I am performing similar experiments but with different components.

Comment: @Shokhet I'm more on the lurker side there, so I don't know for sure, but from my observations, the top users are more inclined to answer if you've done some prep work first.

Comment: @jonsca Got it. I might do some research outside of the network (*is that even possible???*), and then ask there later if I need extra help.

Comment: @SabreTooth What are you playing around with?

Comment: The image sensor mainly

Comment: The consensus here seems to be EE.SE. @jonsca, why don't you write that up as an answer?

Comment: @SabreTooth Good luck!

Comment: @SabreTooth I've [discovered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19707474#19707474) that EE.SE is not the place to ask about consumer electronics, which was what I had intended to do. I'm not sure if your plan has the same problem, but I figured it couldn't hurt to let you know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) has a fairly active [Android](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) tag.

As with any other site on SE, it's important to do some background research before posting your question.  For example, being able to refer to specifics on the datasheets (usually available as PDFs from the chip manufacturers) is important for any type of troubleshooting, and is where the more experienced users will refer you to if you haven't referenced the documentation already.

---

As mentioned in the comments:

> Right now, adding a GPS transmitter/receiver to my $20 tablet, possibly also adding more memory.

As an addendum regarding the above, "modifications" in this case should be changes to the actual circuitry and not consumer-grade add-ons for the platform.  As in all cases, an inquiry on the site's Meta is the right way to go if the tour/help center is not definitive.

Comment: I've [discovered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19707474#19707474) that EE.SE is not the place to ask about consumer electronics, which was what I had intended to do. I believe your answer is still correct, though perhaps this should be made clearer for the benefit of others.

Comment: @Shok That information should be in your question as well.  It was "modifying hardware" that was the ambiguity here.

Comment: You're right. The lack of clarity was my fault; I had mentioned what I was trying to do in the comments to the question, but the question probably should have been worded more clearly.

Comment: @Shokhet A moment after I wrote that I realized that you had mentioned it in the comments, but I got sidetracked last night and never clarified.  No hard feelings, it's just an MSE answer!  :)

Comment: Also, my addendum is not to chastise anyone in particular, just advice for the next guy.

Comment: I didn't take it as chastisement. Thanks for your answer :)